# Crystal Reports invalid parameter index?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, comexception

I'm working with VB2010 C# and CR13. I've created a report with empty parameter fields that I'll fill during runtime using the texts that the user will enter on multiple text boxes. I've created a dictionary that contains the parameter name as the key and the text as value.

```
Dictionary<String, String> textos = new Dictionary<string, string>();
textos.Add("prueba1", textBox1.Text);
textos.Add("prueba2", textBox2.Text);
textos.Add("prueba3", textBox3.Text);
textos.Add("prueba4", textBox4.Text);
textos.Add("prueba5", textBox5.Text);
textos.Add("prueba6", textBox6.Text);
textos.Add("prueba7", textBox7.Text);
textos.Add("prueba8", textBox8.Text);
```

Then I add the value to the report using this:

```
    public void addValues()
    {
        String text;
        String parameter;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> t in textos)
        {
            text = t.Value;
            parameter = t.Key;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                cryRpt.SetParameterValue(parameter, text);
        }
    }
```

The `cryRpt.SetParameterValue(parameter, text);` gives me a **COMException(HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))** which I know it's suposed to mean that the parameter name I've introduced is not the same as the parameter name in the report. The problem is that it **IS** the same since I've copied and pasted it to be sure.

Upon further testing I've discovered that if I cange the parameter name form *prueba1* to just *prueba* it works. So I thought that this happened because the name of the parameter field can't have numbers on it, so I've changed all the names (for example instead of *prueba2*, *test*) and this gives me again the same **Invalid index** excepcion as before.

What is happening?

**edit**

Allright after a lot of testing I realized that I was doing it ok, the problem was with the parameter fields. Instead of creating various parameter fields I was using the same one each time. Sorry And thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: Probably need to drop all parameters from report and recreate them. Then retry. As far as I know, parameter names can have numbers, thats not your problem.

Comment: @aMazing That didn't work

Comment: Check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862733/crystal-report-invalid-index-exception-from-hresult-0x8002000b-disp-e-badin/35954722#35954722

Comment: @Bahman That's how I'm using the `.SetParameterValue()` method. And I'm not using a database, it's just `TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> t in textos)
{
    text = t.Value;
    s.Add(text);
}
```

Then in a new loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
{
    cryRpt.SetParameterValue(i, s[i]);
}
```

And what do you mean about **empty parameter fields**?